# Get the information from CSV file in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, api, csv, yahoo-finance

My app is trying to get the live currency exchange rate from yahoo finance.

The following is my code, when I click the button, `0.1` is always returned (the value return from the API is always NULL). I have tried my java code, it works, but it is not working on the Android Studio after I paste my code in.

Is that the problem of reading csv file or sth else?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void startConvert(View view){
        EditText amount,from,to;
        amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
        from=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.from);
        to=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.to);
        Double many;
        //many=Double.parseDouble(amount.toString());

        Toast.makeText(this,"haha",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Double conv =findExchangeRateAndConvert("EUR", "USD", 1000);

        Toast.makeText(this,Double.toString(conv),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private static Double findExchangeRateAndConvert(String from, String to, int amount) {
        try {
            //Yahoo Finance API

            URL url = new URL("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + from + to + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.length() > 0) {
                return Double.parseDouble(line) * amount;
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return 0.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reformatting your code it is hard to read. Also, you could be more clear when it comes to describing your problem.

Comment: The problem is, when I try to get the exchange rate from yahoo finance API, it always returns null while it is working without using android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one..

```
        URL url = new URL("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + from + to + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        String result = "";
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                 date = RowData[0];
                 value = RowData[1];
                // do something with "data" and "value"
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception
        }
        finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add more parameters to the url connection and I'd save it to a file in order to ensure it's not the problem:

```
URL url = new URL("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + from + to + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
DiS = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(DiS));
String data ="";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((data=rd.readLine())!=null){
    sb.append(data);
}
data = sb.toString();
DiS.close();
connection.disconnect();
File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"currency.csv");
if (!mFile.exists()) mFile.createNewFile();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(mFile);
fw.write(data);
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```